# How do I pick only 5 Excel files and load into sql database using Foreach loop container in SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis

We receive a lot of Excel files, But I need to pick(process) only 5 files each time on the iteration number for a foreach loop container task in Visual Studio 2017. How could I achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not difficult to do.

Comment: How can I configure the foreach loop to load only max 5 files every time it runs?

Comment: On every loop increment variable. Too, on every loop ask if variable > 5.

Comment: Thanks Marko. and how I can stop the process when reach > 5 ?